# Открыть SharedPreferences вне пакета

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences, context

Методы которые предлагает `Context` открывают `sharedPreferences` только из папки пакета приложения, а что, если мне нужно открыть такой файл из внешнего хранилища? Как получить к нему доступ чтобы читать его как `sharedPreferences`

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать `SharedPreferences` с флагом `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE`.

В первом приложении записываем значения:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("some_prefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("SOME_VALUE_KEY", "some_value");
editor.commit();
```

Во втором читаем их:

```
Context context = createPackageContext("%FIRST_APP_PACKAGE%", 0);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("some_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = sharedPreferences.getString("SOME_VALUE_KEY", "Empty value");
```

**Однако**, флаги `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE` и `Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` в `API level 17` помечены как *deprecated* с указанием, что это плохо с точки зрения безопасности.